# Too many arguments for grep?

Tags: shell, command-line, grep, command, glob

Here's what I'm trying to run:

```
grep "this is a test" * | wc -l
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
Argument list too long
```

Basically I want to count how many files in a directory have a specific string in them.

I've seen several questions related to this error, but none of them seem to focus on counting the results afterwards.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should remove the *grep* tag from your posting, because the question is not specific to `grep`. BTW, a good article on this subject can be found [here](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be having too many file in current directory.

You can use `find` with `-exec` option for this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep 'this is a test' '{}' + | wc -l
```